# How do I stop Jquery ajaxForm() from refreshing the page?

Tags: jquery, ajaxform

I have a form that I have been submitting succesfully without page refresh using .ajax(), but I modified my form to include an upload field and it is not uploading. So i tried to use the ajaxForm() method which works ie it posts and uploads but it refreshes the page. How do i stop it from refreshing the page?

I have tried to put a return false and it stops the submit from working entirely.

This is what I have so far

```
        var options = {
            target:     '#post',
            url:        '<?php echo $linkr; ?>',
            success:    function() {
                $("#post").load("<?php echo $linkr; ?>");
            }
        };
        $("form").submit(function () { 
        $(this).ajaxForm(options); 
        return false;
        });
```

This code goes to a blank page but it posts and uploads:

```
             var options = {
                target:     '#post',
                url:        '<?php echo $linkr; ?>',
                success:    function(result) {
                    $("#post").html(result);
                }
            };
            $("form").ajaxForm(options);
```

Just to reiterate, I need it to post and upload WITHOUT the page refresh. Using .ajax() accomplishes this but it does not upload. Putting preventDefault is not working, or maybe Im using it wrong.

Comment: why ur loading the link again?? load("<?php echo $linkr; ?>");

Comment: Its not really nevcessary, its a vestigial from the former coide I had done which was not loading on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

use [`preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/)

```
$("form").submit(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).ajaxForm(options); 
});
```

Comment: that stips the whole form submitting. I have reverted back to a previous state which works. The code is now simply using the ajax() but there is no upload I still need the upload

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and let me know then --

```
   var options = {
        target:     '#post',
        url:        '<?php echo $linkr; ?>',
        success:    function(result) {
            $("#post").html(result);
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you problem is that browsers not really support normal uploading of a file without reloading the page. It is possible using HTML5 or flash though.

You can read this tutorial to get some knowledge how to implement ajax file upload with HTML5
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

or you can use plugins like http://www.uploadify.com/

Comment: what about using iframes mand ajaxForm()? does that not work? lots of sites upload stuff without visible page refresh

Comment: with iframes https://www.google.co.uk/search?client=opera&rls=en&q=upload+file+using+iframes&sourceid=opera&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 But I never done that by myself and it looks pretty scary. My suggestion would be to implement HTML5 with fallback to flash or simple upload for browsers which don't support HTML5.